# A function like lmer?

Tags: r, random-effects-model

Can you suggest me any random effect linear model in R? At the moment I am using **lmer**, but I would like to know if there is any other similar function.

Thank you

Comment: This is answerable as it stands and @slackline has given it a good go, but we could help more if we knew what you saw as the limitations of lmer.

Comment: If you want to search for R packages having to do with a certain topic, use http://www.rseek.org.

Comment: take a look e.g. at http://glmm.wikidot.com/pkg-comparison

Answer (score 5):

There are many similar packages...

- nlme for non-linear mixed-effects
- lme4 for linear and generalized linear mixed-effects models
- blme for bayesian linear mixed effects
- glmmAK for Generalized Linear Mixed Models
- glmmBUGS forGeneralised Linear Mixed Models and Spatial Models with WinBUGS, BRugs, or OpenBUGS
- glmmLasso for variable selection for generalized linear mixed models by L1-penalized estimation

I could go on, but they're all listed at [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html).

Comment: Package nlme also provides function `lme` for linear mixed-effects models. I would prefer `lme4::lmer` for linear mixed-effects models and use `nlme::lme` only if you need to specify an autocorrelation structure (which is usually necessary for the data I'm working with).